# Knockout.js - how to cross-reference objects between two arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I have 2 models:

```
var ProductModel = function(productid, productname, producttypeid, productprice) {
  var self = this;
  self.ProductId = productid; 
  self.ProductName = productname;
  self.ProductTypeId = producttypeid;
  self.ProductPrice = productprice;
}
```

and

```
var ProductTypeModel= function(producttypeid, producttypename) {
  var self = this;
  self.ProductTypeId = producttypeid; 
  self.ProductTypeName = producttypename;
}
```

I use them in a viewmodel:

```
var ProductViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.ProductList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ProductTypeList = ko.observableArray([]);

  //...init 2 array and some misc methods
}
```

In html file:

```html
...
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'row', foreach: ProductList }">
  </tbody>
</table>
...
<script id="row" type="html/template">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductId"></td>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductName"></td>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductTypeId"></td> <!-- I stuck here!!! -->
    <td data-bind="html: ProductPrice"></td>
  </tr>
</script>
...
```

I want my table show ProductTypeName instead of ProductTypeId but I can't pass the ProductTypeId into any function to get ProductTypeName.

Comment: your question is not clear there is 3 type and there is no any model or controller :) You shuld define types and use them in another type after the steps you can call them in your html with a foreach as type instances

Comment: @HamitYıldırım, I think it clearly. I can bind my viewmodel and use it correctly. The `ProductViewModel` maybe a bit similar controller you told about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ProductViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.ProductList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ProductTypeList = ko.observableArray([]);

  //...init 2 array and some misc methods

  self.getProductTypeName = function (productTypeId) {
    var typeId = ko.unwrap(productTypeId),
        found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ProductTypeList(), function (productType) {
           return ko.unwrap(productType.ProductTypeId) === typeId;
         });

    return found ? ko.unwrap(found.ProductTypeName) : null;
  };
};
```

and

```html
<script id="row" type="html/template">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductId"></td>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductName"></td>
    <td data-bind="html: $root.getProductTypeName(ProductTypeId)"></td>
    <td data-bind="html: ProductPrice"></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is that this function is going to be called for every item in ProductList and will go over ProductTypeList many times. 
I much rather map ProductTypeList into something like `{
typeId: typeName,
typeId: typeName
...
}` for quicker access. For that I would use a computed on my main model. And getProductTypeName will use that new computed.

Comment: Yes, but only *after* this turns out to be the performance bottleneck of the page. Everything else is premature optimization.

Comment: You are right here. Just my habbit, since our project backend always sends quite a bit of data. Which is all handled on frontend.

Comment: It's worth to keep it in mind in any case. This is one of the spots I would look at when the page feels sluggish.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, I realize my foul that I didn't unwrap observable object. I can rewrite the your code for same result: `$root.getProductTypeName(ProductTypeId())` and in `getProductTypeName` function, I can use parameter `productTypeId` in any way I want.

Comment: You can do that but that would reduce the flexibility of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have two independent collections that are associated with each other.  You could create a model that can manage that association through computed observables mapping the combined objects.

```
function ProductListModel (products, productTypes) {
    this.Products = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(products, function (product) {
            return new ProductModel(
                product.productId,
                product.productName,
                product.productTypeId,
                product.productPrice);
        })
    );
    this.ProductTypes = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(productTypes, function (productType) {
            return new ProductTypeModel(
                productType.productTypeId,
                productType.productTypeName);
        })
    );

    this.AssociatedProducts = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var products = this.Products(),
            productTypes = this.ProductTypes();
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(products, function (product) {
            var productType = ko.utils.arrayFirst(productTypes, function (productType) {
                return product.ProductTypeId === productType.ProductTypeId;
            });
            return {
                ProductId: product.ProductId,
                ProductName: product.ProductName,
                ProductType: productType.ProductTypeName,
                ProductPrice: product.ProductPrice,
            };
        });
    }, this);
}
```

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var p = new ProductListModel(data.products, data.productTypes);
    this.Products = p.Products;
    this.ProductTypes = p.ProductTypes;
    this.AssociatedProducts = p.AssociatedProducts;
}
```

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'row', foreach: AssociatedProducts }">
</tbody>
...
<script id="row" type="html/template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="html: ProductId"></td>
        <td data-bind="html: ProductName"></td>
        <td data-bind="html: ProductType"></td>
        <td data-bind="html: ProductPrice"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/4bxngf8m/)

Comment: Your solution is good! Now, you can use `ko.computed` instead of `ko.dependentObservable` [ref](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html). But I notice it isn't safe when your app use ajax to load data. In this case, you must load `ProductTypes` first, then `Products`.

Comment: I'm aware of the alias between computed and dependentObservable, I just prefer the latter.  In general, it shouldn't matter which values are loaded first.  Though this particular implementation will depend on the order they're loaded, but that can easily be fixed.